# how back the the first index after scroling to the last index on listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

I use this code to move to next index `listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex +1;` 
but the problem is when I am on the last index and I click the button next that have that code is crash any suggestions to make next button back to the first index after click it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to select next item:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex < listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex += 1;
}
else
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```